# What is the Colorpicker Field available for ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs6

I am trying to find a color picker field to use in my form but it's hard to find any one for ExtJS 6.

Found this https://github.com/sw4/Ext.ux.ColorPicker but I don't know how to bind it to my form.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a [colorfield](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.ux.colorpick.Field.html) component included in ExtJS 6.

**NOTE**

This component resides in a [package](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html). So in order to use it, you need to specify the "ext-ux-colorpick" package name, in the *app.json*, in the *require* config, where additional packages are specified.

Comment: Is there a way to include it using Application or pointing the JS file? I don't use app.json.

Comment: Based on [this thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279609-Use-theme-package-outside-CMD) on sencha forum, it seems that usage of packages without Cmd is not "possible". Although I think you can eventually make it work by manually including and copying files, I would not advise to do that.

Comment: You can get the package and build it, and then include the build artifacts in your application. But then again, you need Cmd for building it :)

Comment: I just have my `app` folder structure inside a `webapp` Java Web Application folder and bind `ext-all.js` in my `index.jsp`. Although I consider `Cmd` the "right" way, I don't like it. I like to quickly and easily change small pieces of my application.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple and elegant color picker in jQuery. Was very easy to use it.

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

start the picker using the form's `afterrender` event.

Was necessary to mix Ext.getCmp with $() jQuery selectors.

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function ( cmp ) {
        var container = this.body.dom.id; // << - The Window ID
        var comp = Ext.getCmp("displayColumn"); // << - The Field
        var el = comp.getEl();
        var displayColumnId = el.id; // << - The Field real ID          

        $("#" + container). // <<- The jQuery way
        $("#" + displayColumnId ). // <<- The jQuery way
    }
}
```